# If a Ruby constant is defined, why isn't it listed by constants()?

Tags: ruby, class, constants

Class names seem to show up when you check for them with const_defined?() but not when you try to list them with constants(). Since I'm interested in listing any defined class names, I'm just trying to work out what's going on. Example:

```
class MyClass
  def self.examine_constants
    puts self.name
    puts const_defined? self.name
    puts constants.inspect
  end
end

MyClass.examine_constants
```

Under Ruby 2.0.0p195, that code gives the following results:

```
MyClass
true
[]
```

Shouldn't the methods agree? What am I missing please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Module#constant` method you're using return all the constants at the current scope. What you might want to use is the class method `Module.constant` which returns all the top-level constants. For instance:

```
class MyClass
  def self.examine_constants
    puts self.name
    puts const_defined? self.name
    puts Module.constants.inspect
  end
end

MyClass.examine_constants
```

Response:

```
MyClass
true
[...lots of other constants, :MyClass]
```

Comment: That's great. I can see all the class definitions, etc, by following your suggestion. Just want to totally understand this: when I call constants() without a receiver, as in my original code, is that a different method or the same method called in a different way so that it gives different results?

Comment: They are different methods. The one you were calling `Module#constants` becomes an instance methods of your class. The other one `Module.constants` is a Class Method (or module method in this case). For reference: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-c-constants

Comment: Excellent. From that link: "This... includes the names of all modules and classes defined in the global scope.